# Linux kernel on virtual machine

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, virtual-machine

I am studying Linux driver programming and in it, it is recommended that I work on self-compiled Linux kernels and not any distributions. I have tried compiling Linux 2.6.9 in ubuntu but the process returns errors in 'make menuconfig' stage.

I would prefer to work with Linux in a virtual environment so that I can fearlessly experiment with the kernel. So, is there any way I can compile and run Linux in a virtual machine (say VMware installed on Windows)? I can use live CDs for the purpose of compiling the kernel.

**So in short, please suggest, how can I compile, install and run Linux kernel in a virtual machine in an error-free way?**

I searched and read [this](http://mitchtech.net/compile-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-detailed/). But after following these steps when I restarted my computer there was no separate Linux 3.2.17 OS. But my ubuntu 12.04 was now showing 3.2.17 kernel. Although this is the first time I could compile a whole kernel on ubuntu without any error, I want to load that kernel on other partition and use it as an independent OS. So, if anyone can tell, what to do in addition to the steps in the tutorial so that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is probably to install some Linux distribution on a VM, such as VMWare or VirtualBox, and continue from there. You could try using a live-cd, but I'm guessing that the lack of persistent storage might get irritating. There are, of course, ways around that, but installing some distribution is probably simpler, and you don't really need that much disk space for it if all you want to do is compile a kernel.

If all you want to do is compile a kernel module, and if you already have some pre-installed Linux environment, you should also note that modern Linux installations allow you to compile modules without the need to re-compile the entire kernel. You will need the kernel source and headers, though. See, for example, [this document](http://www.linuxchix.org/content/courses/kernel_hacking/lesson8).

And BTW, speaking of modern kernels, why did you choose to use 2.6.9? It's almost 8 years old by now. Newer kernels might actually be easier to develop for. Also, there's no guarantee that 
modules developed with such an old kernel would still work with current ones.

Comment: @tristram...thanks for your answer...i have ubuntu as an os...but when i compile linux kernel on that...it returns errors...i am asking how can i solve this problem(that is why i wrote 'error free way')

Comment: @avinash That depends a lot on the errors you are getting, of course. But if you check the link above you'll see that it points to a complete 'compiling the kernel' guide - though I've specifically pointed to the module compilation chapter.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read [this page](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/users/faculty/sandhya/csc256/assignments/qemu_linux.html). This document shows you how to boot your personal kernel on qemu and how to use the debugger on it.

Answer (score 1):

[Kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/) is the right place to start kernel hacking. This website contains a set of rich tutorials about kernel hacking and tweaking just for newbie Linux developers. Also, you can join the community and start contributing to some tiny Linux projects.

For a quick start, follow the instruction from the "[kernel first patch](http://kernelnewbies.org/FirstKernelPatch)" tutorial. Since you're cloning the "origin" remote repository in this tutorial, you'll work on the latest branches of Linux kernel. So, there's no need to worry about working on an old version of Linux. Meanwhile, if you're not comfortable working with git trees, you can always download the latest version of Linux from front page of "kernel.org".